# How to move window if its titlebar is out of screen?

Tags: window-manager, window-management, window-title

In my environment (X server on Windows with 2 monitors) sometimes new Windows appear out of screen so that I can't drag them by mouse and titlebar.

Is there any other (easy) way to move windows in Linux?

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> does not work for me.

**UPDATE**

If I do `xdotool` solution against calculator, the following happens

[image]

i.e. only part of window moves. Also, `xdotools` icon is visible only if mouse is over window interior. Once it is over window title, icon disappears. This may mean that Windows control this part...

Comment: That all depends on the window manager, and how you have it configured...

Comment: Why are you asking here if you are running Windows?

Comment: @jasonwryan I am running Linux, Windows is XServer.

Comment: ...and what window manager are you using?

Comment: @jasonwryan what is window manager here? VcXsrv?

Comment: Who knows, it is a **MS Windows** application.

Comment: what happens if you keep Alt pressed and drag the window (anywhere inside)

Comment: The window manager is the program that controls how windows are shown. It's the program that displays a title bar and reacts when you click the title bar, among other things. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/72549/how-to-determine-which-window-manager-is-running; try `wmctrl -m` (obviously, install wmctrl if it isn't already present).

Comment: @Gilles in my case, when app server and X server are different machines, where should window manager run?

Comment: @jet nothing, I can't drag window this way

Comment: @Dims It can run on either. The window manager is a client of the X server, like other applications; it's a client with some special responsibilities.

Answer (score 3):

A way, as there are lots, is to use `xdotool`, a program for `X` automation.

```
xdotool selectwindow windowmove 100 10
```

will change the cursor to indicate you should select a window. When you click on it then the window should move so its top corner is in a 100 pixels from the left of the virtual screen and 10 pixels down from the top of the virtual screen. Adjust the 100 and 10 so the window appears on the physical screen(s).

`xdotool` can search by name if you want a solution that doesn't involve selecting the window with a mouse.

`wmctrl` is an example of another program that can do the same task.

Comment: Great thing, thanks, but didn't work in my case...

Comment: Sorry about that. We need to understand your environment more. Do you have one large window in which each of the X application windows appear, or do each of the X applications appear apparently as separate applications on your MS windows machine? If the latter then the window manager is almost certainly running as part of the X server application. If you have one large window in which everything appears then the window manager may be running on your unix/linux machine. One term that is often used is `rootless`.

Comment: I have one big window, but is is "hidden" and can be "shown". I was thinking it is called "rootless". Probably I can setup true "rootless" in VcSrv...

Comment: Showing the big window is probably a good idea. Does it have scrollbars? Is it bigger than your screen? I would suggest *not* to go `rootless`, in my experience it causes more issues than it help.

Comment: No it's just black and covers entire area of my 2 montors and since the are located in an irregular way, the area has "gaps" and sometimes windows fall into them...

Comment: Definitely sounds that you are running rootless https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Implementations so it is up to Microsoft to move the windows.  Do the applications (e.g. xcalc) show up in the windows taskbar? Standard technique is to click on the background, use ALT-TAB to select the application, use ALT-Space and the `M` to start the window move and then use the arrow keys to position it.

Comment: Windows way does not work too... Probably, Linux' windows capture keystroke events :)

Comment: So to ask again in a different way, if you run xcalc, does xcalc show up as a new thing on your **microsoft windows** taskbar? If you left-click **outside** any window, hold down the alt key and press tab does the microsoft windows switcher come up, and if so can you switch to xcalc?